# How to paste a part of an image in the same coordinates I cut it from?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I want to cut a specific part of an image, then paste it in another image in the same coordinates I cut it from. So, if I cut it and it was in (100, 112) then I paste it in (100, 112) in the other Image, not in the center.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Photoshop you can do that in several methods

1. Copy the desired part of the image and click <kbd>CTLR</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and in the other file, click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
   or
2. Select the part of your image you want to copy and drag it to the new file while holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>; it will paste the selected area in the same place
   or
3. After copying your part of the image, paste it by `Edit > Paste Special > Paste in Place`

Comment: I wasn't aware of n.2! Nice!

Comment: cool!! ... I can fight the giants :)

Comment: also not aware of N.2. Supergood!

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you have whatever you want to duplicate in a separate layer, you can right click that layer in the "Layers" list and choose "Duplicate Layer..." then choose in the "Destination" drop down - "New" and it will open a new empty document with only that layer in that same position.

Comment: this is also a good one