# Paste in the exact same location you cut from in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, layers

All I could find so far on this site are posts with that exact question, but for [Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42628/how-to-paste-a-part-of-an-image-in-the-same-coordinates-i-cut-it-from).

The only way I see currently is to copy and paste the x/y coordinates in a temporary text file, then cut and paste into (or move to) the new layer, and then reapply the coordinates again. An ugly workaround, in my opinion. Is there a better way?

*(Inkscape v0.92)*

Comment: Try *Edit > Paste in Place*, or the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+V

Comment: Thank you. Didn't see that.

Comment: @BillyKerr Please make it an answer, so that you can get the tick!

Comment: First I thought: Use duplicate. But no, user wants to cut and then paste in same spot again. So only one item before and after. Weird request. Would you like to explain what you are using this for please? If you just want to have it in your clipboard, you could copy instead of cut and re-paste... Now I am really intrigued.

Comment: @MartinZaske - to be honest I don't think there's enough to make it a full answer. If you can think of more to add, be my guest. I agree it's an odd thing to want to cut and then paste something in place, and without more information we can't really know what exactly the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @MartinZaske I've used Paste in Place to move an object to a new layer. It's a very useful command to help organise a complex image.

Comment: It's not that uncommon. Don't make me look so weird! (^^ ) Sometimes you want to organize the objects in your document. For instance, moving to another layer helps to clarify if you are confused about the many objects sitting on top of each other (z-index). You can quickly hide and show layers with that eye icon.

Comment: What about right-click : Move to layer, @z3z ?

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru What about using the Objects dialog for this?

Comment: @Moini, I did not see that right-click option. The objects window didn't prove very useful or insightful so far, so I didn't think of checking that. In fact, I didn't expect it to be helpful with this.

Comment: It's also useful for bringing objects outside nested groups.

Comment: Paste in Place is clear, but how do I paste the object in the same place **on another page**?